# Potential energy of the dipole-dipole interaction for two parallel dipole moments

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential-energy, dipole

I am looking for an equation that gives me the potential energy of the interaction between two parallel dipoles.

Comment: This is pretty much formula based. Find the field due to one dipole near the other, then use $U=-\vec p \cdot \vec E$

Comment: I think, according to homework policy, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Hint:

Interaction energy of two dipoles :

$$U=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0r^3}\left( \mathbf{p}_1.\mathbf{p}_2-3\left ( \mathbf{p}_1.\hat r )(\mathbf{p}_2.\hat r\right) \right)$$

Comment: Could you explain what is the meaning of $\hat r$?

Comment: It's the unit vector in direction of $\vec{r}$, i.e. $\hat{r}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this formula? Any book?

Comment: @user171780 See problem 4.8 (p. 165) in Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics (3rd ed).

Comment: Not sure why you call this a "hint".